# Can't Unlock from Constraint Z Axis

Tags: objects, axis

I am a very big noob at Blender. I make GFX for a game called Roblox, and I am currently working on a project to help a friend learn Blender. As shown in the picture, I was able to get the arm to bend by going to the Local Z axis, but when I was on a Windows 7 laptop, I didn't need to. The Z axis won't unlock and I am very confused.

https://gyazo.com/3a9e457e412c9996ab8b4173993577a0

Comment: what version is this? pls use the latest version if you want bugs and errors fixed!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the windows dude, maybe just keyboard binding.
If you are trying to animate something would recommend to look if the model has bones (armature(right upper corner list)), if so check if skeleton(armature) is in Rest position,
click on Pose Position. Then just change object mode to pose mode & should be ready to go.
Cheers.

Comment: There was no armature in the Blender list. There were different parts, but no armature or skeleton there. The GIF shows what I see.
https://gyazo.com/f4d3fd61458673e5f23647c465831396